# Rails show maximum amount of a Bid for every id product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, schema, erb

I'm trying to print out in the index view page next to every product the maximum amount of the bid for that product. So the outcome should be like this in the index view:

Banana   (maximum amount for banana)
Table    (maximum amount for table)
 etc

I Know how to print out the maximum of the total of all products, but not the maximum amount of each product. That being said I attach my code:

ROUTES:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get "/new", to: "users#new"
  # get "/index", to: "products#index"
  get "/products", to: "products#index", as: :products

  get "/new_products", to: "products#new"
  #  el form_for siempre necesitará un path en forma de as: ... ya que no le sirve solo la url
  post "/products", to: "products#create"
  get "/products/show/:id", to: "products#show", as: :product
  post "/bids/new_bid", to: "bids#create"
  # post "/new_bid", to: "bids#create"
  post "/products", to: "bids#pass_bid_amount"

end
```

Bids controller:

```html
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  
  def create
    user= User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if Time.now < params[:product_deadline]
      @bid= Bid.new(amount: params[:amount].to_i, user_id: user.id.to_i, product_id: params[:product_id].to_i)    
      if @bid.save
        redirect_to product_path(@bid.product_id)
      else
        render plain: "something went wrong"
      end
    else
      render plain:" Too late"
    end 
  end

  def pass_bid_amount
    @bid= Bid.new(amount: params[:amount].to_i, user_id: user.id.to_i, product_id: params[:product_id].to_i)
    @bid.save
    render "index"
    # redirect_to products_path(@bid.product_id)  
  end

end
```

INDEX.HTML.ERB:

```html
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <p><%= link_to product.title, product_path(product.id) %></p>
  <p><% %></p> 
<% end %>  

<p><%=  Bid.maximum(:amount) %> </p>

This maximum amount is not of every single object but the total of all products

<p><%= @products.inspect %></p>
<p><%= Bid.new.inspect %></p>
<!-- <p><%= @bid.inspect %></p> -->
```

And what I see in the Browser is this:

```html
banana

table

tree

99999999

This maximum amount is not of every single object but the total of all objects

#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 1, title: "banana", description: "this is a fruit", user_id: nil, deadline: "2016-11-22 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01", updated_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01">, #<Product id: 2, title: "table", description: "this is an object", user_id: nil, deadline: "2016-11-22 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01", updated_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01">, #<Product id: 3, title: "tree", description: "this is a tree", user_id: nil, deadline: "2016-11-22 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01", updated_at: "2016-11-12 12:40:01">]>

#<Bid id: nil, amount: nil, user_id: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

SCHEMA:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161109151534) do

  create_table "bids", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_bids_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bids_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is the correct response in the INDEX.HTML.ERB file:

```html
<% @products.each do |product| %>




<p><%= link_to product.title, product_path(product.id) %> 
<%  maximum_bid = product.bids.max_by {|bid| bid.amount }  %>
<p><%= maximum_bid.amount%></p>



</p>
<p><% %></p> 
<% end %>  

<!-- <p><%=  Bid.maximum(:amount) %> </p> -->




<p><%= @products.inspect %></p>
<p><%= Bid.new.inspect %></p>
<!-- <p><%= @bid.inspect %></p> -->
```

And now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Show your product controller.

Or use something like this:

```
@products.joins(:bids)
    .where("max_bid = (select max(amount) from bids where product_id = product.id"))
```

Comment: I got the answer! Yours sounds to me more complex. Thanks anyway!